# Execute command line argument in Node.js with existing global variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm executing something in the command line like so:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'some command';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
});
```

It work's fine, but it doesn't seem to have the parents scope. For instance I have a `$app` global variable that is available in the calling function.

But in the 'some command' I run it is not available. Is there any way to pass this in? Basically I wanna have access to `$app` in my child command line command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## passing parameters:

You should be able to do something like:

```
var options = {
    env : process.env
}

exec(cmd, options, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    //...
});
```

This will give you access to all the environment variables from the parent.

Even if the environment variable is not set you can create one in the parent node program on the fly, e.g.:

```
// in parent program before calling exec.
process.env.userInputtedName = "Joe";
```

The child now has access to that environment variable.

See
[child_process.exec documentation](https://gist.github.com/leommoore/4484379#passing-options)

## passing objects:

If is an object you wish to pass an object from the parent to the child you can used `JSON` functions to encode and decode , e.g.

```
process.env.details = JSON.stringify({
   custom : 'object',
   containing : [ 'complex', 'structures' ] 
});
var options = {
    env : process.env
};
```

Then decode the `JSON` in your child program (e.g. for JS):

```
var importedObject = JSON.parse(process.env.details);
```

For more involved inter-process communications you might want to look at a network library such as net or zeroMQ.

Comment: @Rob: Hi Rob. I have tested the above and it works perfectly. Is this solution acceptable or did I mis-interpret your question? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I need to pass a whole object in. With functions and it's own environment, not just a variable. I think I'm not approaching it correctly. It's actually just another node module (Sequilze) which also comes with CLI version. But in this case I should probably be doing a required and manually trying to make the call rather then using the CLI.

Comment: @Rob : ok. It was not clear to me from the question. I have updated it but it still won't give you access to functions. Not sure if you want to control the parent from the child but it sounds like you have your work cut out :)

Comment: Ya, I think I may be over complicating it. @chriskelly

Comment: This was perfect for me! I was trying to figure out how to use AWS Lambda to send an SNS message to a child shell script. Your gist gave me the answer I needed. I sent the entire JSON object as an env variable. That did the trick. Thank you so much @chriskelly